# Can someone explain the output from the pvclust function in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, hierarchical-clustering, pvclust

In the `pvclust` package in R, there is the `pvclust()` function. In the example provided in the function help file, there's the function:

```
boston.pp <- pvpick(boston.pv)
```

This is supposed to print out the clusters with high p-values. The output of this function is:

```
$clusters
$clusters[[1]]
[1] "rm"   "medv"

$clusters[[2]]
[1] "zn"  "dis"

$clusters[[3]]
[1] "crim"    "indus"   "nox"     "age"     "rad"     "tax"     "ptratio" "lstat"  


$edges
[1] 3 5 9
```

I have a lot of trouble understanding what the output means, especially since I have very limited technical background on cluster analysis. In particular, I don't understand the meaning of the vector of names under each cluster. Can someone explain this for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pvclust/pvclust.pdf
describes pvclust:

> For data expressed as (n x p) matrix or data frame, we assume that the data is n observations of p objects, which are to be clustered. The i’th row vector corresponds to the i’th observation of these objects and the j’th column vector corresponds to a sample of j’th object with size n

Output of pvpick:

> cluster - a list of character string vectors. Each vector corresponds to the names of objects in each cluster.

Have you plotted dendrogram of pvclust output? pvpick `clusters` output just lists internal points (pvclust treats each **column** in boston dataset as a point) in some cluster which you will see in dendrogram if you plot it.
[image]

Comment: does pvclust cluster variables and hclust cluster observations by default?

Comment: @xyy, yes, you can try boston.hc <- hclust(dist(Boston)) to be sure about this.